# How did I flag before the comment was posted?

Tags: bug, comment-flags

Here's what my flagged posts looks like:

> [image]

And here's [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282293/what-is-the-limitation-of-actionscript-2-0#comment25058657_17282293):

> [image]

I shouldn't have flagged this comment, but my question is: Why is the time on my flag earlier than the time the comment was posted?

Comment: Are you sure the author did not remove their comment, only to repost the same (or a similar) one later?

Comment: My understanding is that if the comment is removed (either by a moderator or voluntary), my flag would be marked as helpful. I also don't think it's a timezone issue because the timezone is localized (and I didn't move anywhere, been in the same place since last year).

Comment: Ah, true, it should indeed work like that. The mystery deepens...

Comment: Interesting.  The minutes are different too, so it's not a bug with timezones.  Are you sure that that line refers to the flagging of that specific comment?  It looks like you flagged more than one comment from that user on that question.

Comment: Yep, because a moderator dismissed my flag just now as helpful, and the comment was removed.

Comment: Could it be an edited comment?

Comment: No because there isn't an edit icon, and edits timeout in 5 minutes or so.

Comment: Perhaps there's a disparity somewhere since DST was just this past Sunday? Still doesn't explain the minutes though.

Comment: Are you sure you are not perhaps in a time machine? Just to make sure. Jokes aside I doubt someone can track this bug down. It's from like 1.5 years ago. Maybe they kept record of time changes in the server? If not I don't know how. By the way, why you just now found it like that after 1.5 years?

Comment: I was going through my flags list for undismissed flags, I found a comment flag and decided to flag it again.